# Create indicator variable within panel data in R

Tags: r, panel

I feel this should be easy but at a loss, and hoping y'all can help.  I have panel data, by `id` with variables, here just `v1`:

```
id  v1
A   14
A   15
B   12
B   13
B   14 
C   11
C   12 
C   13
D   14
```

I would simply like to create a dummy variable indicating whether a value of `v1` (say `12`) exists in the panel for `id`. So something like:

```
id  v1  v2
A   14  0
A   15  0 
B   12  1
B   13  1
B   14  1 
C   11  1
C   12  1 
C   13  1
D   14  0
```

I feel this should be simple but can't figure out an easy one line solution.

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(v2 = as.numeric(any(v1 == 12)))
```

Or as per @akrun suggestion:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, v2 := any(v1 ==12)+0L, id]
```

*Note*: Adding `0L` to the logical values created by `any()` will switch `TRUE/FALSE` to `0`s and `1`s.

Another approach could be using `ave`:

```
df$v2 <- with(df, ave(v1, id, FUN = function(x) any(x == 12)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  id v1 v2
#1  A 14  0
#2  A 15  0
#3  B 12  1
#4  B 13  1
#5  B 14  1
#6  C 11  1
#7  C 12  1
#8  C 13  1
#9  D 14  0
```

Comment: Or `setDT(df)[, v2 := any(v1 ==12)+0L, id]` with `library(data.table`) or using `ave`

Comment: is there any reason to want 0s and 1s instead of F/T? Also, is using `+0L` faster than `as.integer`, or just more concise?

Comment: @MichaelChirico 0s and 1s were used to match OP desired output. I don't know if he has a specific purpose for that. Concerning `+0L` vs `as.numeric` they both should be pretty equivalent in terms of speed.

Comment: OK, just checking to see if there was perhaps some substance behind the style. My benchmarks suggest `as.integer` wins out for large vectors, but  on a scale of microseconds for 10000-length vectors.